# Making sentence using "distaste"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct

> Distaste about apple.

I want to say that he dislikes apple. Am I correct?

Comment: If what you mean is *He dislikes apple*, that's a perfectly good way of putting it. No variant involving the word ***distaste*** will be anywhere near as "natural" in normal speech.

Comment: This sort of question is more suited for http://ell.stackexchange.com/, which is designed for people learning how to speak English.

Answer (score 1):

> When you're **disgusted** by something, or simply **dislike** it, you have a
>   [**distaste**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distaste) **for** it.

- You might have such a [distaste](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dis-&allowed_in_frame=0) for the smell of meat cooking that you only go to vegetarian restaurants.

[The preposition is "for".](http://www.myenglishgrammar.com/list-11-prepositions/427-prepositions-after-nouns.html)

- appetite for
- craving for
- desire for
- **distaste for**

> dislikes apple => distaste **for** apple.